# Using same display list in multiple objects of the same class

Tags: java, variables, object

I'm writing a voxel type game in java but I have performance issues, imagine that I have a class "Cube", there are thousands of objects created based on this class, this class has in it's core a display list, what I want to know is if there is some way to create that display list only once and use it multiple times without using interfaces or other classes.

I hope you understand and thanks for your help.

Comment: Of course you can. But you give too little information for a better answer.

Comment: What more information is needed?

Comment: ok, I read only descrition but it's in question.. assuming @Baadshah guessed correctly what you mean, his answer is good

Answer (score 0):

By making that list as `STATIC`.

```
public static list:
```

getter to that variable

```
public static list getStaticList(){
    {
    return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring that list as `static` will do what you need.

Hope it helps.